# how to add google traffic api

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

hii everyone.. I want to show local traffic conditions in my android app..like this

http://maps.google.com/maps?ie=UTF8&hl=en&layer=t&ll=38.899049,-77.017593&spn=0.268261,0.6427&z=11

i tried to use 
`mapview.setTraffic(true).` but this dosen't show me anything. just showing a simple map. how can i apply this traffic api in my app..if anyone knows..please guide me..

or can i show this as an intent...

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=61454)

> Live traffic data is available in
>   major cities in the United States,
>   France, Britain, Australia, and Canada

Your local area happens to be india

If you are having issues with MapView refresh, call

```
mapView.invalidate()
```

[image: (RE) EDDIT:]

Comment: sorry..but not getting you completely.. the link which you give me is telling about complete layers..but not telling that how to add these layers in android app.

Comment: Where are you testing your app. You should know what you dont get traffic info for Indian cities.

Comment: ok..now i get you..so is there anyway so that we can check this app from India..can we set any locale or anything else..

Comment: @nimi open the map of the new york city in you map

Comment: i tried what you sad, but it is showing only map of new york..not showing traffic position there

Comment: Is their any possibility to check that traffic data is available or not for a particular location